# extract specific line from a file using awk

Tags: file, awk, line

The data in the file:

```
...
... 
a b c d letters
f g h i letters
j k     letters
...
...
```

Using,

```
awk '/letters/' file
```

The result is:

```
a b c d letters
f g h i letters
j k     letters
```

However I want to have the following result (without tab and 'letters' word and single line would be better):

`a b c d e f g h i j k`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you going to identify the lines? Is there some identifying mark on lines (like the word letters will be on each line?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
awk '$NF=="letters"{sub($NF,"");s=s $0}END{sub(/ *$/,"",s);print s}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "...
... 
a b c d letters
f g h i letters
j k     letters
...
..."|awk '$NF=="letters"{sub($NF,"");s=s $0}END{sub(/ *$/,"",s);print s}'                                                                                                   
a b c d f g h i j k
```

so output in oneline, without trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
output=$(awk '$NF=="letters" {$NF="";print}' file)
echo $output   # without double quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can search for letters, delete the last field, and concatenate the rest of the line into a single variable A, then print that variable out at the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/letters/ {$NF="";A=A $0}
END{print A}
```

It doesn't remove any replications. But you didn't ask for that.